# Using sed to update crontab job minutes and hour from script

Tags: javascript, regex, unix, sed, cron

I'm using a script (Javascript, Node) to update a single line of my `crontab` file, identified by a `#comment` at the end.

I think I don't fully understand how to regex within `sed`, more particularly how are match groups defined and used after it.

Say I want to update the minutes and hour of my cron job. I now use two different lines I figured out by pure trial and error after lots of searching:

To update the minutes:

```
"crontab -l | sed -e 's/[0-9]* \\([0-9]*\\) \\(.*#mycomment\\)/ mynewminutes \\1 \\2/' | crontab -"
```

And to update the hour:

```
"crontab -l | sed -e 's/\\([0-9]*\\) [0-9]* \\(.*#mycomment\\)/\\1 mynewhour \\2/' | crontab -"
```

I would like to do this in a single line of code, but I can't get it to work even though I feel I'm so close. Any ideas? I got to a point where I only see a bunch of `/` and `\` without meaning within the sed command, if somebody could explain that command and regex to me I'd be so thankful.

Example:

Existing cron job which will execute `command /path` at 11:00

```
00 11 * * * command /path #mycomment
```

If I execute the above commands with `mynewminutes = 30` and `mynewhour = 20` cron will execute the task at 20:30, with the resulting updated cron entry in the cron file:

```
30 20 * * * command /path #mycomment
```

---

Please note both lines are quoted and escaped because they are Javascript strings which I'm calling using Node's `exec`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte sorry, fixed!

Comment: You should also show one (or several) example string(s) with the expected result.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte updated with an example, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed` by default uses the [BRE (Basic Regular Expression)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) syntax, that's why capture brackets are escaped with a backslash. But to figure a literal backslash in a Javascript string, you also need to escape it. That's why brackets are preceded by two backslashes.

About how to change the hour and the minutes in a single replacement, it isn't very complicated:

```
sed -e 's/^[0-9][0-9]* [0-9][0-9]* \(.*#mycomment\)/mynewminutes mynewhour \1/'
```

pattern details:

```
^             # start of the line anchor
[0-9][0-9]*   # one or more digits
              # space
[0-9][0-9]*   #
              #
\(.*#mycomment\) # capture group 1: all until #mycomment
```

replacement: `\1` refers to the content of capture group 1

or better: *(this way you avoid capture groups)*

```
sed -e '/#mycomment/s/^[0-9][0-9]* [0-9][0-9]*/mynewminutes mynewhour/'
```

*(that replaces the two first numbers on the line only if the `/#mycomment/` condition succeeds)*

Note that using `awk` is an interesting alternative since it's designed to work with fields:

```
awk '/#mycomment/{$1=mynewminutes;$2=mynewhour}1'
```

Once in your Javascript string you obtain:

```
"crontab -l | sed -e 's/^[0-9][0-9]* [0-9][0-9]* \\(.*#mycomment\\)/mynewminutes mynewhour \\1/' | crontab -"
```

or

```
"crontab -l | sed -e '/#mycomment/s/^[0-9][0-9]* [0-9][0-9]*/mynewminutes mynewhour/' | crontab -"
```

or:

```
"crontab -l | awk '/#mycomment/{$1=mynewminutes;$2=mynewhour}1' | crontab -"
```

About the awk version, if you want a leading 0, you have to enclose the new hour or minutes between quotes:

```
"crontab -l | awk '/#mycomment/{$1=30;$2=\"05\"}1' | crontab -"
```

Comment: Sir, this is awesome! It's working flawlessly. You're the ultimate regex ninja, thank you so much! I was really struggling with the \1 and \2 capture groups. Thank you again!